# "Description Language:" field in apt-cache showpkg

Tags: apt

The output of `apt-cache` provide a field named "*Description Language:*" in about every file, and - as far as I was able to find out - they all are empty. From `man 8 apt-cache`

> For the specific meaning of the remainder of the output it is best to
>   consult the apt source code

As I'm not able to <strike>use</strike> interpret the source myself:

**Question**: What would be a possible string / value / … for this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Description Language" field contains the language code for any available translation you have downloaded. These are stored in `...Translation-lang` files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` (where `lang` is the language code). `apt-get` downloads the appropriate `Translation` files for the language it's run in; thus for example

```
sudo LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 apt-get update
```

will download French translation files.

On my system `apt-cache showpkg dpkg` gives one empty entry (corresponding to the original description in the `Packages` files) and one `en` entry (corresponding to the "translation" in the `Translation-en` files).

Many packages have descriptions translated into other languages; see for example the [French description of `dpkg`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/dpkg).